# Change devise params from user[email] & user[password] to email and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating an API and was wondering if it is possible with the devise gem and with Rails in general, to change the the params such that user[email] changes to email and user[password] changes to password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the devise `sessions/new` view to change signin form.

Just type `rails generate devise:views` to generate devise views and then play with them.

Notice that you must handle this in the SessionsController, because the default Devise controller doesn't know the changes you made, like new params name.
To override or create custom devise controller check the documentation here:
[Configuring Devise Controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

For general purpose it's not clear what you need to do.
Speaking of API, or any other controller you can handle sent params with no restriction.
If you get `params[:user][:email]` (because of default devise form) you are free to write it in `params[:email]` and do what you want.

Comment: Since I'm intending the sessions controller (via routes like /api/login) to be handling direct json calls, I won't need to re-write views. I was hoping there would be a cleaner method of rewriting the params but I could just go down the manual route for now.